# Gamma kernel Density estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, gamma-function, estimation, gamma-distribution

The standard kernel Density estimator of $f$ is given by 
$$\hat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)$$
and the gamma kerenel 
$$ K_{x/b+1,b}(t)=\frac{t^{x/b}e^{-t/b}}{b^{x/b+1}\Gamma(x/b+1)}$$
where $b$ is the smoothing parameter ($b=h$ in this case) satisfying $b \to 0$ and $nb \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$

I read a [peaper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1004165218295), where the author obtain directly

$$\hat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_{x/b+1,b}(X_i)$$
but I do not know how this happen directly.

Could someone help me?

Any participation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is $$\hat{f_1}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_{x/b+1,b}(X_i)$$ 
and there is 
$$\hat{f_2}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_{\rho_b(x),b}(X_i)$$ 
which are definitions .

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the paper.  The author isn't saying that the definition $$\hat f_{\!1}(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n K_{x/b+1,b}(X_i)$$ corresponds to a specific choice of kernel and bandwidth in the previous equation $$\hat f(x) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)$$ (which is called Eq. 2.1 in the paper).  Rather, the author is **defining** a gamma kernel density estimator with that form.  Indeed, you can see that this is necessary because with (2.1), the kernel must be defined for $x < X_i$.  There are no choices of $K$ from the gamma family that would make that work since its support is on $[0, \infty)$.